# What type must a parameter be in order to accept a member of a struct?

Tags: c#

I am trying to set up a function which allows me to pass a member of a struct as a parameter so it can be used with nameof() inside of the function. I am hoping to set up a function that can return the offset of a member in a struct using Marshal.OffsetOf(), but I want to configure the function so that I can use nameof() instead of hardcoding member names as string.

I have tried to configure the parameter using Generics, Object, Type and nothing seems to work.

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(getStructMember(TestStruct.a)); //Does Not Work

            Console.WriteLine(nameof(TestStruct.a)); //Does Work, however I cannot use this for my function

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string getStructMember(Type member)
        {
            return nameof(member);
        }
```

The expected result of getStructMember() should be "a", but I cannot compile as I can not figure out how to configure this function's parameters.

Comment: You can't use `nameof` this way. `nameof(member)` will always return `"member"`. Maybe you want a `MemberInfo`? Why must you use a `getStructMember` function anyway. Why can't you just do `Console.WriteLine(nameof(TestStruct.a));`?

Comment: @Sweeper Assuming I use MemberInfo, how can I configure my function to allow 'TestStruct.a' as a parameter? I am hoping to set up a function that can return the offset of a member in a struct using Marshal.OffsetOf(), but I want to configure the function so that I can use nameof() instead of hardcoding member names as string

Comment: You can't. There is no way to directly pass `TestStruct.a`. There has been some suggestions about an `infoof` operator, but [it's unlikely to be added](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue/).

Comment: Can you [edit] the part about writing a function to get the offset of a member into the question? Because right now your question is essentially an XY question.

Comment: `Marshal.OffsetOf` takes a string directly, so your method should take a string as parameter too. Then you can pass `nameof(TestStruct.a)`.

Comment: @Sweeper Done, Sorry. Seems that i will just have to use string as the parameter type and use nameof() in the function call. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nameof` operator always evaluates to a string, so your method should accept a string:

```
    static int GetOffSet<T>(string member)
    {
        ...
        ... Marshal.OffsetOf<T>(member) ...
        ...
    }
```

And you can call it like this:

```
GetOffset<TestStruct>(nameof(TestStruct.a))
```

Note that you would have to specify `TestStruct` twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work only with a specific structure you may also optimize(so you do not have to specify struct name twice) Sweeper's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337198/3745022) with a bit of `Expression` manipulations

```
private static IntPtr GetOffset<T>(Expression<Func<TestStruct, T>> expr)       
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expr.Body; // Perhaps, add some additional sanity checks.
    return Marshal.OffsetOf<TestStruct>(memberExpression.Member.Name);
}
```

That can be used as

```
GetOffset(o => o.Value)
```

Or for a more generic solution

```
private static IntPtr GetOffset<TStruct>(Expression<Func<TStruct, Object>> expr)       
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)(((UnaryExpression)expr.Body).Operand);
    return Marshal.OffsetOf<TStruct>(memberExpression.Member.Name);
}
```

To be used as

```
GetOffset<TestStruct>(o => o.Value)
```